# How to get the value of a CPointer in Visual Works

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

The following C function populate a C struct in Visual Works (is working ok):

```
<C:int ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file (const char * filename,  VOID * pkey)>
```

Now a second function is defined as:

```
int ssh_userauth_try_publickey (ssh_session session, const char * username, const ssh_key pubkey)
```

In Smalltalk:

```
<C:int ssh_userauth_try_publickey (VOID session, const char * username, const VOID pubkey)>
```

If i call the second function (`ssh_userauth_try_publickey`) with the populated argument (with no transformation) of the first function (`ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file`) it fail.

So `VOID * pkey` has to match `const VOID pubkey`.

In **GemStone/S** this is done with `#'&ptr'` and `#'ptr'`, so `#'&ptr'` will get the value of the pointer (the CPointer’s value will be passed and updated on return).

Reading **DLL & C Connect User’s Guide** does not yield result yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

use void** in your first function and void* in your second function

## Long answer

In C, `void` means "nothing" and if you have a return type of void that means you don't return anything.
But `void*` means pointer to nothing (...that i know about)... basically you get a pointer to something where you don't know what it is. But it's still a pointer, which is not nothing.

If you have a function that produces a value not via return but via parameter, you need to pass a pointer so that the function can set its value. You can do that via void* but that's unintentional. Consider the following *wrong* C code:

```
void var;
myFunc(&var);
```

`myFunc` would take a void* as parameter in order to fill its value, but a variable of type void is wrong because what would be its value. In correct C you would do it like that:

```
void* var = NULL;
myFunc(&var);
```

Here the type of `var` is clearly a pointer and its value is even initialised. For `myFunc` there's no real difference here, except that it'll now have a `void**` as parameter.

So if you modify `ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file`'s declaration to have a void** parameter and change `ssh_userauth_try_publickey`'s declaration to accept a `void*` parameter, you should be fine.

Comment: After your proposed changes i got the same results. Still more research needed but it seems that replace void* with void** does not yield any change in the final result.

Comment: You also seem to have the same problem with the `session` parameter in the `ssh_userauth_try_publickey` function. You can have a look at `Win32SystemSupport>>createPath:in:` for an example. It calls `Win32SystemSupport>>RegCreateKey:named:reserved:class:options:sam:security:result:disposition:` where `void*` is the first parameter (input) and `void**` is the 8th parameter (output).

Comment: Well this was a difficult nut to crack :)
Thank you for point out this code example (Win32SystemSupport).
After some research the problem was a previous call to C function```ssh_key_new``` which answer an empty ```ssh_key```. But #contents message fail. It seems that the content of the pointer to (ssh_key_new) is somehow lost. After replacing ```ssh_key_new``` with ```External.CVoidType void pointerType gcMalloc``` everything works fine now. In the last call to C functions simple send #contents and i got the right result. Still i will research more on the lost content of ```ssh_key_new```

Comment: It turn out to be more simple than i expected. ```ssh_key_new``` has to be defined as:
```<C:VOID** ssh_key_new()>``` instead of ```<C:VOID ssh_key_new()>```. Now with the new definition #contents works ok with ```ssh_key_new```. The summary of the history is when you need to use a pointer value/content then use ** in the correct place !!